# pass path to VM options in Windows IntellijIDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need use VM options in my project. I use IntellijIDE and I add this option:

```
-Dconfig.localfile=C:\Users\Pavel\IdeaProjects\work\prj\project\local-dev.conf
```

But I get error:

```
ConfigNotFoundException: C:\Users\Pavel\IdeaProjects\work\prj\project\local-dev.conf is not found
```

On mac os it is work but I use Windows 10. Maby I have error with `/\`? How can I pass path to VM options?

Comment: Did you try using the forward slashes?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 -Dconfig.localfile=file:C:\Users\Pavel\IdeaProjects\work\prj\project\local-dev.conf
```